# add_meta_box in unique administration page

Tags: wordpress

I wanna add a metabox in unique ID page (front-page). Someone can explain, why with this code in my functions.php file :

```
function add_metafields()
{
        echo '<label for="add_video">add video : </label>';
        echo '<input type="url" value="http://" name="add_video">';
} 

function initialize_metabox()
{   
    global $post;
    if ('7' == $post->ID )
    {
        add_meta_box('video_metabox', 'add new video', 'add_metafields', 'page', 'side', 'high');
    }

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'initialize_metabox');
```

The global variable is empty. However, this code works perfectly :

```
    function add_metafields()
{
        global $post;
        if ('7' == $post->ID )
        {
            echo '<label for="add_video">Ajouter une video : </label>';
            echo '<input type="url" value="http://" name="add_video">';
        }
} 

function initialize_metabox()
{   
    add_meta_box('video_metabox', 'Ajouter un lien vidéo', 'add_metafields', 'page', 'side', 'high');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'initialize_metabox');
```

What is the problem with the first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. At the time WordPress triggers `admin_menu` hook, no posts is available.
2. Your `add_metafields` callback is called when `add_meta_box_page` hook is triggered. At this time, the `$post` is always available.